# CSS to float button next to accordion drop down

Tags: css

I am trying to float a button next to a jQuery accordion panel.  Currently it looks like this:
[image: not floating :(]

Here is the markup

```
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" style="width: 80%;" role="tablist">
</div>

<div id="export" style="width:20%">
   <form method="post" action="/InstrumentList/Export">
      <div class="button-container">
         <button id="btnSubmit" class="ui-button-text-only ui-button ui-igbutton ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="width: 100%;" value="Export" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
      </div>
   </form>
</div>

<div id="grid">
</div>
```

I have put inline styling in at the moment but I will move that out to a CSS file once I have managed to get it working.  The grid div is represented in the picture by the light grey row which needs to stay positioned under the dark grey rows.

Comment: Is the `#accordion` div floated? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: It's not at the moment, that is what I am asking - what elements do I need to float to get them next to each other and the grid underneath still positioned as it is?  Or should I use elements other than divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you meant to close the `#accordion` div before opening the `#export` div.

Your question preempts the answer: you should be able to simply put a `float:left` property on each div.

```
#accordion {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}
#export {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

You may need to also ensure that for both divs the `margin-left` and `margin-right` are both set to zero.

**Update:** to ensure that the `#grid` does not overlap the floating elements, you should use `clear:both` on it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you need this:

```
#accordion, #export {
    float: left;
}

#grid {
    clear: both;
}
```